# Advantages/Disadvantages on developing iPhone apps with Appcelerator Titanium instead Apple development

Tags: javascript, iphone, titanium, appcelerator

I have a new project which is an iPhone application. for that I have 2 possibilities to build it:

- using Apple classic style (xcode, objective-c, etc)
- using [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/) and continue using javascript as an interface to access all the iPhone features to create my app.

**I've noticed the absence of a separated interface file like XIB on Titanium*

Since I'm kind of faithful about the future of javascript as the universal way to develop, I'm pending more to the titanium side, but I still not sure if it's the right thing to do or if I should stick with the 'classic' way of creating apps.

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted a [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034558/how-advantageous-is-phone-gap/4038085#4038085), similar to this about [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com) and [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/)... but to be more specific, the approach I have taken with these frameworks is to use the framework first and then leverage plugin or extensions the framework provides when I need to get down in the weeds.

I believe knowing the "classic" style can only benefit you now that these frameworks are relatively new and probably not complete. It allows you to code your way through the last mile when necessary.

So to sum it up, I would start with [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com) or [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/) and get the thing going, and fall back on the classic way when you get stuck