# Has anyone used phonegap framework and how would they rate it?

Tags: iphone, android, cross-platform, cordova

Since I have found nearly nothing about phonegap development on stackoverflow as of yet, I thought I would ask the community what they think about this framework. Is it easy to use? Do the benefits of using a crossplatform framework outweigh the restriction of javascript/html/css only development. My company wants to develop a simple merchant type application, but they are worried about reinventing the wheel by first developing an iPhone app and then also developing an android version. What do you guys think?

Comment: no experience with this yet but I've heard some chatter about it across the 'nets.  I think you sort of answer your own question in that HTML/Javascript/CSS have their limitations, if you expect that your application needs to push these limits in order to achieve some visual "flash" for lack of a better word, then you're probably best off making a common service-layer/model and separate UIs, if it just needs to be cheap/easy to update across platforms and doesn't need a lot of "flash" then HTML is the way to go... still good question for those who have experience

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161004/using-phonegap-for-native-application-development/5162539#5162539

Comment: possible duplicate of [How advantageous is PhoneGap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034558/how-advantageous-is-phonegap) and about a half dozen nearly identical questions.

Comment: This is a legitimate question. Dori's comments are way off the mark...! We are about to spend considerable money on a framework, likely phone gap and I want to know if it is worth it.! Please reopen this question as cross-platform development is a large consideration for enterprise application development.!